# Continuous Integration with Blue Ocean, Github and Nuget causes path too long

Tags: jenkins, github, nuget, jenkins-blueocean

NUnit.Extension.VSProjectLoader.3.7.0

I try to get a build chain to work with Jenkins Blue Ocean where the sources are in GitHub and additional dependencies are in nuget.

When I restore packages I get the error after the specific package NUnit.Extension.VSProjectLoader.3.7.0:

```
Errors in packages.config projects

    The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

On the agent machine the path is very short: `C:\guinode\` on top of that additional length is added making the packages folder the following size:

`MyGitProject` is replacing my actual project name, the length is equal.

```
C:\guinode\workspace\MyGitProject_master-CFRRXMXQEUULVB4YKQOFGB65CQNC4U5VJKTARN2A6TSBK5PBATBA\packages
```

Checking the package on the agent machine shows that NUnit.Extension.VSProjectLoader.3.7.0 was loaded completely.

Checking a local installation and replacing the first path of the package I can find two files that are 260 characters or longer.
They belong to an internal project, so I have a chance of influencing that.

None of the directories are 248 characters or more.

So the immediate solution for me is to redeploy the internal reference package.

My question for future reference is if I can do something to the `packages` location or something to `workspace\MyGitProject_master-CFRRXMXQEUULVB4YKQOFGB65CQNC4U5VJKTARN2A6TSBK5PBATBA` so that I save some characters per default.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) it can be possible to modify the 260 length rule.

- If you prefix your file with '\\?\'  eg:  '\\?\C:\guinode\workspace...' then long path will be in use ( a little bit more than 32000 char). I hope settings `JENKINS_HOME` to this kind of path make all process use that (I'm not sure)
- On recent Windows version (10.1607, 2016?) there is an option in the registry to enable long path. Set 1 to the following key: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled (Type: REG_DWORD)` and restart the process.

Comment: Cool Idea but I can not get it to work in the environment. ´?´ is recognized as an illegal character Both in the Launch of the Agent and when injected into nuget restore  -PackagesDirectory parameter. It looks like something like this could work on Windows 10. That is not applicable to my build server though.